# Qt - I have a QPushButton QVector, which one was pressed?

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qvector

I have `QLineEdit`s and `QCheckBox`es `QVector`s - I also have a `QPushButton` `QVector` which when an element is pressed, the corresponding `QLineEdit` and `QCheckBox` are also removed.

How can I find out which button was pressed to determine which index to remove? Currently I am just using `Checkbox`es right now which is easy but a little bulky for my liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward way is to use `QObject::sender()` in the button press slot to find out which button emitted the signal. You should then iterate over the vector of buttons:

```
QObject* obj = sender();
for(int i=0;i<buttonVector.count();i++)
{
    if( obj == qobject_cast<QObject *>(buttonVector[i]))
    { 
      ...
    }
}
```

One workaround is to use `QObject::setObjectName` and set some names to the buttons you add :

```
button.setObjectName(QString("%1").arg(i));
```

And in the slot you can retrieve the button number using the object name :

```
void MainWindow::buttonClicked()
{
    QPushButton *button = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(QObject::sender());

    int number = button->objectName().toInt();
}
```

Another way is to use the `QSignalMapper` class which collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal. So you can have one like:

```
QSignalMapper * mapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
QObject::connect(mapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SLOT(buttonClicked(int)));
```

When newing your buttons, you can connect the `clicked()` signal of the button to the `map()` slot of `QSignalMapper` and add a mapping using `setMapping` so that when `clicked()` is signaled from a button, the signal `mapped(int)` is emitted:

```
button = new QPushButton();

QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()),mapper,SLOT(map()));
mapper->setMapping(button, i);
```

This way whenever you click a button, the `mapped(int)` signal of the mapper is emitted containing the button number and consequently `buttonClicked` is called with a parameter containing the button number.

Comment: There's also QButtonGroup, although for this use case is comparable to QSignalMapper

Comment: The QSignalMapper is a lovely solution which I managed to implement. Only thing I have found to be a little bit annoying is the fact that if I delete a button, I have to manage the mappings manually since mapping->removeMapping() doesn't resize anything. Thanks @Negat !